# Using Rebar3 how to use Common Test so it places the beam files in _build section not test folder?

Tags: erlang, common-test, rebar3

When I use rebar3 with Common test as follows: `rebar3 ct` it compiles (generates beam files for) all my code into the test folder. Everything works but less than ideal.
How do I have it place them in the _build/test/MyApp/ebin section?
Eunit does this great, but Common Test does not.

Project Layout:

```
MyApp/
    apps/
       MyApp/
          include/
          priv/
          src/
          test/
              ct/
              eunit/
```

I want the beams to go into the _build section like eunit does:

```
MyApp/
   _build/
      test/
       lib/
         MyApp/
            ebin/
```

My Common Test logs folder is going into the _build/test/logs which is cool. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: Update: It appears that the compiled files are going into the ebin folder for both eunit & common tests, but in addition they are also going into the test folder when common test is used. (rebar3 ct). So how do we stop them from going into the test folder?